# How many view controllers can I have in the navigation stack at once?

Tags: ios

Users of my app can continually load new instances of the same view controller with different pieces of information. Is there a maximum amount of view controllers that can be in the navigation stack?

Edit:

This particular view controller shows postings made by other users and I put a section that shows users related postings, so when they go to tap one one they see another set of related postings and so on. I've seen many apps like this in the past. Do their developers do anything to prevent memory crashes or do they just assume users won't tap on enough of them to make the app crash?

Comment: That should depend upon the memory available to your application.

Comment: Why would you keep stacking more and more? What will the user be doing that they would keep adding more and more view controllers and then being able to go back, one by one?

Comment: There is no any  limit specified , However as ZeMoon said when your app memory increases it will crash

Comment: This particular view controller shows postings made by other users and I put a section that shows users related postings, so when they go to tap one one they see another set of related postings and so on. I've seen many apps like this in the past. Do their developers do anything to prevent memory crashes or do they just assume users won't tap on enough of them to make the app crash?

Comment: A single `UIView` doesn't need it's own separate `UIViewController`. Without more detail, one should think you should redesign things. Care to provide us with more details?

Comment: Just did @dfd. What do you mean by a single UIView doesn't need it's own separate UIViewController? Think Instagram. When you follow a profile, you're provided with a set of other profiles to follow and so on. This is similar to the aforementioned function in my app.

Comment: If I may paraphrase what the other commenters are saying 'Navigation Controller is not the UI mechanism you are looking for'. A Navigation Controller is designed to provide a finite stack of view controllers that the user realistically may want to pop *one at a time* back to the start. It is not an efficient way of  implementing  a browser style interface with a history of viewed pages.

Comment: Alright, I understand now @Ali Beadle. I think limiting the number of view controllers in the navigation stack might be the best thing I could do here. Maybe i'll hide the related careers section after a certain number of related careers have been tapped. Your comment would probably be a good answer if you want to post it.